# Sankey plot with the riverplot package

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, riverplot

Enchanté.

EDIT: Solution

As pointed out by MartineJ and emilliman5, nodes should be uniquely labelled (below).

```
library("riverplot")
nodes<-structure(list(ID = c("2011+", "2011-", "2016+", "2016-"), x = c(20, 
20, 30, 30), y = c(50, 40, 50, 40)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
edges<-structure(list(N1 = c("2011+", "2011-", "2011+", "2011-"), N2 = 
c("2016+", "2016-", "2016-", "2016+"), Value = c(461, 7, 0, 46)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

river <- makeRiver(nodes,edges)
riverplot(river)
```

I've been toying to plot a Sankey diagram/riverplot (using the [riverplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverplot/riverplot.pdf) package) of how cancer registrations evolve over time, though this code has bought me little success so far. Could anyone possibly direct me on the faults of this code?

```
Warning message: In checkedges(x2$edges, names(x2)) : duplicated edge information, removing 1 edges
```

Here is the suspect code:

```
library(“riverplot”)

edges<-structure(list(N1 = c("+", "-", "+", "-"), N2 = c("+", "-", "-", "+"), Value = c(664L, 50L, 0L, 46L)), .Names = c("N1", "N2", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

nodes = data.frame(ID = unique(c(edges$N1, edges$N2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nodes$x = c(1,2)
rownames(nodes) = nodes$ID

rp <- list(nodes=nodes, edges=edges)

class(rp) <- c(class(rp), "riverplot")

plot(rp)
```

And the data, which is included in code:

```
N1    N2    Value
 +     +     664
 -     -      50
 +     -       0
 -     +      46
```

Eternally grateful.

Comment: Could you tell us what the problems, errors, warnings were?

Comment: Many thanks for the edit suggestions.

Comment: The warning verbatim is: Warning message:
In checkedges(x2$edges, names(x2)) :
  duplicated edge information, removing 1 edges

Comment: It would be a lot easier fot the community if you provided a minimal dataset. It would be even better if you would provide a great reproducible example. Looke [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for an explanation.

Comment: Addressed. Relatively new to both R and Stackoverflow. Patience appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nodes need to be named uniquely and then use the `nodes$labels` to change it back:

```
library(riverplot)

edges<-structure(list(N1 = c("+", "-", "+", "-"), N2 = c("+", "-", "-", "+"), Value = c(664L, 50L, 0L, 46L)), .Names = c("N1", "N2", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
edges$N1 <- paste0(edges$N1, "a")
edges$N2 <- paste0(edges$N2, "b")
nodes = data.frame(ID = unique(c(edges$N1, edges$N2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nodes$x = c(1,1,2,2)
nodes$labels <- as.character(substr(nodes$ID, 1, 1))
rownames(nodes) = nodes$ID

rp <- list(nodes=nodes, edges=edges)

class(rp) <- c(class(rp), "riverplot")

plot(rp)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the same value multiple times in N1 (and in N2). Try to make them all different (per column) and try again, f.i.:

N1: plus1 minus1 plus2 minus2

If you want to **show** only + and -: in makeRiver, there is an option **node_labels **

Comment: Appreciated. Renamed nodes—and success!